# Adding setVisible() to markers created in a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am creating a neighbourhood map using google maps API.I have added some locations and created markers. I want to add a search filter feature, such that the user can search those locations by their name. It should include a text input field or drop-down menu that filters the map markers and list items to locations matching the text input or selection.
The list items filtering works fine but the markers(locations) are not filtered.
So I want to ask how can I use setVisible() property to hide and display the markers in my code.

This is the filter module:

```
 function viewModel(markers) {
 var self = this;
 self.filter = ko.observable(''); // this is for the search box  
 self.items = ko.observableArray(locations); 
 self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
 var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
 if (!filter) {
  return self.items();
     } else {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(id) {
    return stringStartsWith(id.title.toLowerCase(), filter);

  });
   }

 });
```

This is the full code of my .js file.

```
var map;
    var locations = [
    {title: 'The Red Fort', location: {lat: 28.6562, lng: 77.2410}},
    {title: 'Humayun\'s Tomb', location: {lat: 28.5933, lng: 77.2507}},
    {title: 'India Gate', location: {lat: 28.6129, lng: 77.2295}},
    {title: 'Lotus Temple', location: {lat: 28.5535, lng: 77.2588}},
    {title: 'Akshardham Temple', location: {lat: 28.6127, lng: 77.2773}},
    {title: 'Lodhi Gardens', location: {lat: 28.5931, lng: 77.2179}},
    {title: 'Raj Ghat', location: {lat: 28.6406, lng: 77.2495}},
    {title: 'Jama Masjid', location: {lat: 28.6507, lng: 77.2334}},
    {title: 'Gurudwara Bangla Sahib', location: {lat: 28.6264, lng: 
     77.2091}},
     {title: 'Qutub Minar', location: {lat: 28.5244, lng: 77.1855}},
  ];
    var center =[{lat : 28.5244, lng : 77.1855}];

var markers = []; // Creating a new blank array for all the listing markers.

var styles = [
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#19a0d8' }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'administrative',
    elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#ffffff' },
      { weight: 6 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'administrative',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#e85113' }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'road.highway',
    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#efe9e4' },
      { lightness: -40 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'transit.station',
    stylers: [
      { weight: 9 },
      { hue: '#e85113' }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'road.highway',
    elementType: 'labels.icon',
    stylers: [
      { visibility: 'off' }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [
      { lightness: -100 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'poi',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { visibility: 'on' },
      { color: '#f0e4d3' }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'road.highway',
    elementType: 'geometry.fill',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#efe9e4' },
      { lightness: -25 }
    ]
  }
];

function initMap() {
  // Constructor creates a new map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center[0],
    zoom: 13,
    styles: styles,
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  var largeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var defaultIcon = makeMarkerIcon('0091ff'); // this is the default marker icon.
  var highlightedIcon = makeMarkerIcon('FFFF24'); // this is the state of the marker when highlighted.
  var activeIcon = makeMarkerIcon('0F0');


  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var position = locations[i].location; // Get the position from the location array.
    var title = locations[i].title;
    marker(locations);

}
    // Create a marker per location, and put into markers array.
    function marker(locations)
    {var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: position,
      title: title,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      id: i,
    });
    locations[i].marker = marker; // we made marker a property of the locations and stored info of each marker
    wikiLink(locations[i]);

    markers.push(marker); // Push the marker to our array of markers.
    // Create an onclick event to open an infowindow at each marker.
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      populateInfoWindow(this, largeInfowindow);
      this.setIcon(activeIcon);
    });
    bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
    /*
    marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
      this.setIcon(highlightedIcon);
    });
*/
    marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
      this.setIcon(defaultIcon);
    });
  }
  // Extend the boundaries of the map for each marker
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  function wikiLink(location) {
    location.url = '';
    var wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + title + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';

    //If you cant get a wiki request, throw an error message.
    /*
    var wikiError = setTimeout(function() {
      location.url = 'Unable to find the request';
    }, 8000);
    */

$.ajax({
      url: wikiUrl,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonp: "callback",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var url = response[3][0];
        console.log(url);
        location.marker.wikiurl = url;
        console.log(location.url);
        //clearTimeout(wikiError);
      }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
      error = 'Unable to find the request';
        alert("Post error: " + error);
    });
  }
}

// This function populates the infowindow when the marker is clicked. We'll only allow
// one infowindow which will open at the marker that is clicked, and populate based
// on that markers position.
function populateInfoWindow(marker, infowindow) {
  // Check to make sure the infowindow is not already opened on this marker.
  if (infowindow.marker != marker) {
    infowindow.setContent(''); // Clearing the infowindow content to give the streetview time to load.
    infowindow.marker = marker;
    // Making sure the marker property is cleared if the infowindow is closed.
    infowindow.addListener('closeclick', function() {
      infowindow.marker = null;
    });

    // In case the status is OK, which means the pano was found, computing the position of the streetview image, then calculate the heading, then get a
    // panorama from that and set the options
    var getStreetView = function(data, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latLng;
        var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(
          nearStreetViewLocation, marker.position);
          infowindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div><hr><div id="pano"></div><div><a href=' + marker.wikiurl + '> Click here for more info </a></div>');
          var panoramaOptions = {
            position: nearStreetViewLocation,
            pov: {
              heading: heading,
              pitch: 30
            }
          };
          var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
          } else {
            infowindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div><hr>' + '<div>No Street View Found</div>');
          }
        };
        var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        var radius = 500;
        // Use streetview service to get the closest streetview image within 50 meters of the markers position
        streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(marker.position, radius, getStreetView);
        infowindow.open(map, marker); // Open the infowindow on the correct marker.
      }
  }


  // This function takes in a COLOR, and then creates a new marker icon of that color.
  // The icon will be 21 px wide by 34 high, have an origin of 0, 0 and be anchored at 10, 34).
  function makeMarkerIcon(markerColor) {
        var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
          'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=1.15|0|'+ markerColor +
          '|40|_|%E2%80%A2',
          new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          new google.maps.Point(10, 34),
          new google.maps.Size(21,34));
        return markerImage;
      }

function viewModel(markers) {
  var self = this;
  self.filter = ko.observable(''); // this is for the search box, takes value in it and searches for it in the array
  self.items = ko.observableArray(locations); // we have made the array of locations into a ko.observableArray
  self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
      return self.items();
         } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(id) {
        return stringStartsWith(id.title.toLowerCase(), filter);

      });
    }

  });

  var stringStartsWith = function (string, startsWith) {
       string = string || "";
       if (startsWith.length > string.length)
           return false;
       return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
   };

  // this should show the infowindow if any place on the list is clicked
  this.showInfoWindow = function(place) {
       google.maps.event.trigger(place.marker, 'click');
  };

}
$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

This is .html file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Map of my favourite city - New Delhi</title>
  <link href="css/map_styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/knockout-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <span class="menu-title">List of places</span>
      <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: filter" placeholder="Search from the list">
      <ul class="" style="list-style-type: none;" data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
        <li>
        <a href="#"><span data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.showInfoWindow"></span></a>
      </li>
      </ul>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <h2>Famous places in New Delhi</h2>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Click here</span>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="map-error" class="map-error"></div>
  <script src="js/newmap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/maperror.js"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCwUdUoC9ZiRbFC3et89fPK3tXIVO8D2sI&callback=initMap"
     onerror="mapError()"></script>
  <script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you show the html?

Comment: I have added the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this question :) It was an interesting exercise. I'm not sure my answer will satisfy you, because it re-initializes the map every time a filter is done. I'm not sure how to get around that, because the viewModel and the initMap method are separate. But it does what you asked for.

1. Modified your `initMap()` method to take an array parameter, holding boolean values. If the array is not defined the markers' visibility are defaulted to `true`
2. Modified the viewModel, by creating an array to hold boolean values. The array is emptied every time the viewModel is called, and the markers are spliced to hold the original values only (One of the areas I'm sure you can improve on). Inside your `ko.utils.arrayFilter()` method, if returned value is `true`, I push a `true` value to the array as well. At the end of the array, I call the `initMap()` method again, with this array as input. Now only the locations which are filtered out as `true` in the search will be visible on re-initializing.
3. While applying the bindings I provided `markers` variable as input to the viewModel. (I think you had already intended to do this, but forgot).

**Update:**

4. Concerning the error you're getting in the comment, it's because I replaced your lines

`<script src="js/newmap.js"></script>
 <script src="js/maperror.js"></script>`

with an empty `<script>` tag and placed the entire JS code in there. To avoid confusion, I'll remove all the snippets of code I had put above and show the entire file here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.4.2.js'></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <style>
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <span class="menu-title">List of places</span>
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: filter" placeholder="Search from the list">
        <ul class="" style="list-style-type: none;" data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.showInfoWindow"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <h2>Famous places in New Delhi</h2>
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Click here</span>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="map-error" class="map-error"></div>


    <script>
        var map;
        var locations = [
            {title: 'The Red Fort', location: {lat: 28.6562, lng: 77.2410}},
            {title: 'Humayun\'s Tomb', location: {lat: 28.5933, lng: 77.2507}},
            {title: 'India Gate', location: {lat: 28.6129, lng: 77.2295}},
            {title: 'Lotus Temple', location: {lat: 28.5535, lng: 77.2588}},
            {title: 'Akshardham Temple', location: {lat: 28.6127, lng: 77.2773}},
            {title: 'Lodhi Gardens', location: {lat: 28.5931, lng: 77.2179}},
            {title: 'Raj Ghat', location: {lat: 28.6406, lng: 77.2495}},
            {title: 'Jama Masjid', location: {lat: 28.6507, lng: 77.2334}},
            {title: 'Gurudwara Bangla Sahib', location: {lat: 28.6264, lng:
                            77.2091}},
            {title: 'Qutub Minar', location: {lat: 28.5244, lng: 77.1855}},
        ];
        var center = [{lat: 28.5244, lng: 77.1855}];

        var markers = []; // Creating a new blank array for all the listing markers.

        var styles = [
            {
                featureType: 'water',
                stylers: [
                    {color: '#19a0d8'}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'administrative',
                elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                stylers: [
                    {color: '#ffffff'},
                    {weight: 6}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'administrative',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [
                    {color: '#e85113'}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [
                    {color: '#efe9e4'},
                    {lightness: -40}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'transit.station',
                stylers: [
                    {weight: 9},
                    {hue: '#e85113'}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'labels.icon',
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: 'off'}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                stylers: [
                    {lightness: 100}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [
                    {lightness: -100}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: 'on'},
                    {color: '#f0e4d3'}
                ]
            }, {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                stylers: [
                    {color: '#efe9e4'},
                    {lightness: -25}
                ]
            }
        ];

        function initMap(array) {
            // Constructor creates a new map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: center[0],
                zoom: 13,
                styles: styles,
                mapTypeControl: false
            });

            var largeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var defaultIcon = makeMarkerIcon('0091ff'); // this is the default marker icon.
            var highlightedIcon = makeMarkerIcon('FFFF24'); // this is the state of the marker when highlighted.
            var activeIcon = makeMarkerIcon('0F0');


            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var position = locations[i].location; // Get the position from the location array.
                var title = locations[i].title;
                marker(locations);

            }
            // Create a marker per location, and put into markers array.
            function marker(locations)
            {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: position,
                    title: title,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    id: i,
                    visible: (array ? array[i] : true)
                });
                locations[i].marker = marker; // we made marker a property of the locations and stored info of each marker
                wikiLink(locations[i]);

                markers.push(marker); // Push the marker to our array of markers.
                // Create an onclick event to open an infowindow at each marker.
                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    populateInfoWindow(this, largeInfowindow);
                    this.setIcon(activeIcon);
                });
                bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
                /*
                 marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
                 this.setIcon(highlightedIcon);
                 });
                 */
                marker.addListener('mouseout', function () {
                    this.setIcon(defaultIcon);
                });
            }
            // Extend the boundaries of the map for each marker
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

            function wikiLink(location) {
                location.url = '';
                var wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + title + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';

                //If you cant get a wiki request, throw an error message.
                /*
                 var wikiError = setTimeout(function() {
                 location.url = 'Unable to find the request';
                 }, 8000);
                 */

                $.ajax({
                    url: wikiUrl,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp: "callback",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.length);
                        var url = response[3][0];
                        //console.log(url);
                        location.marker.wikiurl = url;
                        //console.log(location);
                        //clearTimeout(wikiError);
                    }
                })
                        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                            error = 'Unable to find the request';
                            alert("Post error: " + error);
                        });
            }
        }

  // This function populates the infowindow when the marker is clicked. We'll only allow
  // one infowindow which will open at the marker that is clicked, and populate based
  // on that markers position.
        function populateInfoWindow(marker, infowindow) {
            // Check to make sure the infowindow is not already opened on this marker.
            if (infowindow.marker != marker) {
                infowindow.setContent(''); // Clearing the infowindow content to give the streetview time to load.
                infowindow.marker = marker;
                // Making sure the marker property is cleared if the infowindow is closed.
                infowindow.addListener('closeclick', function () {
                    infowindow.marker = null;
                });

                // In case the status is OK, which means the pano was found, computing the position of the streetview image, then calculate the heading, then get a
                // panorama from that and set the options
                var getStreetView = function (data, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                        var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latLng;
                        var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(
                                nearStreetViewLocation, marker.position);
                        infowindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div><hr><div id="pano"></div><div><a href=' + marker.wikiurl + '> Click here for more info </a></div>');
                        var panoramaOptions = {
                            position: nearStreetViewLocation,
                            pov: {
                                heading: heading,
                                pitch: 30
                            }
                        };
                        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
                                document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
                    } else {
                        infowindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div><hr>' + '<div>No Street View Found</div>');
                    }
                };
                var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
                var radius = 500;
                // Use streetview service to get the closest streetview image within 50 meters of the markers position
                streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(marker.position, radius, getStreetView);
                infowindow.open(map, marker); // Open the infowindow on the correct marker.
            }
        }


        // This function takes in a COLOR, and then creates a new marker icon of that color.
        // The icon will be 21 px wide by 34 high, have an origin of 0, 0 and be anchored at 10, 34).
        function makeMarkerIcon(markerColor) {
            var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                    'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=1.15|0|' + markerColor +
                    '|40|_|%E2%80%A2',
                    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    new google.maps.Point(10, 34),
                    new google.maps.Size(21, 34));
            return markerImage;
        }

        function viewModel(markers) {
            var self = this;
            self.filter = ko.observable(''); // this is for the search box, takes value in it and searches for it in the array
            self.items = ko.observableArray(locations); // we have made the array of locations into a ko.observableArray
            var arrayofMarkersForVisibility = [];
            self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
                if (markers.length>10) markers.splice(10,10);
                var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
                if (!filter || filter =="") {
                    arrayofMarkersForVisibility = [];
                    for (var i in markers){
                        //markers[i].setVisible(true);
                        arrayofMarkersForVisibility.push(true);
                    }
                    initMap(arrayofMarkersForVisibility);
                    return self.items();
                } else {
                    arrayofMarkersForVisibility = [];
                    for (var i in markers){
                        arrayofMarkersForVisibility.push(false);
                        //markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function (id) {
                        var somestring = stringStartsWith(id.title.toLowerCase(), filter);
                            if (somestring){
                                arrayofMarkersForVisibility[id.marker.id]=true;

                                //markers[i].setVisible(true);
                            }
                            if (id.marker.id ==markers.length-1) initMap(arrayofMarkersForVisibility);

                        return somestring;

                    });
                }

            });

            var stringStartsWith = function (string, startsWith) {
                string = string || "";
                if (startsWith.length > string.length)
                    return false;
                return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
            };

            // this should show the infowindow if any place on the list is clicked
    this.showInfoWindow = function(place) {
         google.maps.event.trigger(place.marker, 'click');
    };

  }
  $(function(){
      ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(markers));
  });
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCwUdUoC9ZiRbFC3et89fPK3tXIVO8D2sI&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. But when I implement this I get the error:                                                                                                jQuery.Deferred exception: google is not defined ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: Updated the answer